# How do I reclaim unused blob space for my Azure VHD

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage

Maybe I don't fully understand how Azure charges for VHD storage.

When I started out, I had a 120gb VHD with only ~30gb used. I was only getting charged for roughly 1gb per day for Azure. As I filled up the hard drive, the daily usage grew as expected. I ended up using 100gb of the drive and was getting hit with roughly 3.6gb per day from Azure. That makes perfect sense to me.

The other day, I free'd up a lot of space on the VHD and now I only use 30gb again where the other 90gb is free space. However, it seems that I'm still getting charged for roughly 3.6gb per day.

Could someone help explain this to me? Do I need to do something to reclaim the free space? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to manually reclaim unused space by executing the following PowerShell command (starting from Windows Server 2012 / R2):

```
Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter F -ReTrim
```

More information: [Release unused space from your Windows Azure Virtual Hard Disks to reduce their billable size](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/releasing-unused-space-from-your-windows-azure-virtual-hard-disk-reduce-billable-size/)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the files on the VHD may be deleted, you still pay for the space they once consumed.  Check out this post by the Windows Azure storage team - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/28/exploring-windows-azure-drives-disks-and-images.aspx.

In the "Storage Capacity" section - 
"It is also important to note that when you delete files within the file system used by the VHD, most operating systems do not clear or zero these ranges, so you can still be paying capacity charges within a blob for the data that you deleted via a disk/drive."

Comment: Is it possible to re-zero unused space so Azure can reclaim it?